# How to make Hexagone frame a picture in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a rectangle image. I want to cut that image to Hexagone image as given below.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: I tried to make two images join together yet one layer comes up to other, I couldn't merge both. @Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create your Hexagone 
2. Place it on top of the image you want to cut, reasize it untill it fits the size and position you want.
3. Select the hexagon (cmd/ctr + click on the Hexagone layer)
4.Go to the picture layer and create a mask
This should mask the picture you ant inside a hexagone or any other shape

Now in order to create the hexagone got to the polygon tool and change the sides ammount to whatere you want (6-7-8)there you'll fint the round corners too 
 [image]

Comment: But to create Hexagone, where is its option in Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a polygon shape too you can use in photoshop, it slides out if you press continuosly on the rectangle too (shortcut u). You can use this tool on a new layer and subtract the image from the shape by right-clicking and creating a selection path

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions